# sql query-> how will i get the id from the table

Tags: sql

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT order_id 
FROM oc_order 
WHERE customer_id=7  
  AND order_status_id=5
```

Here the customer_id 7 is hard coded. Instead of hard coding I have to get the id from the table how will I get that?

The table updates each time whenever a customer is logged in

Comment: `from the table` ... from _which_ table?  You've only shown us one so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT order_id 
FROM oc_order 
WHERE customer_id=(select customer_id from customer where ..)
  AND order_status_id=5
```

Considering you have `Customer` table where you have new `customer_id` stored

Answer (score 0):

Or `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT o.order_id 
FROM oc_order o
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
AND o.order_status_id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT order_id
FROM oc_order
WHERE customer_id in (SELECT customer_id 
                      FROM oc_order)
AND order_status_id=5
```

Comment: @Prdp see my EDIT, I change "WHERE" to "SELECT", my mistake ^^!